# Beautifulsoup get content without next tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I have some html code like this

```
<p><span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>123</p>
```

I used Beautifulsoup,and here's my code :

```
html = '<p><span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>123</p>'
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
p = soup1.text
```

I get the result  'abc123'

But I want to get the result '123' not 'abc123'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there’s more than one thing inside a tag, you can still look at just the strings. Use the `.strings` generator:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<p><span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>123</p>'
>>> soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
>>> soup1.p.strings
<generator object _all_strings at 0x00000008768C50>
>>> list(soup1.strings)
['abc', '123']
>>> list(soup1.strings)[1]
'123'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to remove the span tag and then get the text you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p><span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>123</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for span in soup.find_all("span", {'class':'map-sub-title'}):
    span.decompose()

print(soup.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `extract()` to remove unwanted tag before you get the text from tag like below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p><span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>123</p>'
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
soup1.p.span.extract()

print(soup1.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways, is to use `contents` over the parent tag (in this case it's `<p>`).

If you know the position of the string, you can directly use this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p><span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>123</p>', 'lxml')
>>> # check the contents
... soup.find('p').contents
[<span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>, '123']
>>> soup.find('p').contents[1]
'123'
```

If, you want a generalized solution, where you don't know the position, you can check if the type of content is `NavigableString` like this:

```
>>> final_text = [x for x in soup.find('p').contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString)]
>>> final_text
['123']
```

With the second method, you'll be able to get all the text that is directly a child of the `<p>` tag. For completeness's sake, here's one more example:

```
>>> html = '''
... <p>
...     I want
...     <span class="map-sub-title">abc</span>
...     foo
...     <span class="map-sub-title">abc2</span>
...     text
...     <span class="map-sub-title">abc3</span>
...     only
... </p>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> ' '.join([x.strip() for x in soup.find('p').contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString)])
'I want foo text only'
```

Answer (score 1):

Although every response on this thread seems acceptable I shall point out another method for this case:

`soup.find("span", {'class':'map-sub-title'}).next_sibling`

You can use `next_sibling` to navigate between elements that are on the same `parent`, in this case the `p` tag.